# Publish a netcore 3 app to raspberry pi 3 (32 bits/x86)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, cefsharp

I have a problem with my netcore 3 project that is using CefSharp.Offscreen.
I am trying to publish it for raspberry pi 3 with the command: "dotnet publish -p:Platform="x86""
but when I try to execute it on my raspberry with this command: "dotnet myApp.dll" then I have this error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly '/home/pi/appTest/myApp.dll'. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

I trying republishing it a lot of time with other arguments but I can't make it work, maybe the problem is from CefSharp ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ummmm ... I don't think that there are any `x86` pi's. Try `armhf` ..

Comment: the target "armhf" is not recognized..

Comment: There is currently no ARM build of CefSharp. Unless the version of Windows has an x86 emulation layer then it's not possible to run on an ARM device currently.

Comment: Actually looking at the tags you've listed Linux,  where CefSharp is Windows only as it's built with VC++ which Microsoft haven't ported to Linux.

Comment: Oh okay, so since it's impossible, would you have an alternative to Cefsharp that would work on Linux? (Arm 32 bits). Because in fact I need a web browser in my project (which is never displayed, just used in the background) in order to retrieve information from the internet (it's called a scraper I think). I've looked on the internet but I don't find much... Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I found a solution, instead of using Cefsharp (which is the problem I think) I used another library called "Puppeteer-sharp" which is working quite the same (and is most importantly working on my raspberry pi):
https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp
Thanks for your help!